# Is there any evidence that laptops in airplanes might be used for terrorist attack?

Tags: united-states, aviation, security, airport-security

For some airports in the Middle East passengers are not allowed to bring electronic devices bigger than smartphones into the cabins. According to some news pages (e.g. [this article](http://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/apr/25/us-considers-banning-laptops-on-flights-from-uk-airports/%20%22this%20article)) this ban should be extended to European airports within the next days.

This article also states that according to the Trump administration

> [...] “intelligence” emerged that terrorists favoured “smuggling explosive devices in various consumer items”.

Is there any evidence supporting this statement?

Comment: The problem is that there are many, many ways to smuggle a bomb on an airplane. If you prevent one, someone will find a new way to smuggle it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your title and body ask different questions, but in Somalia last year, a bomb disguised as a laptop was used to attack a plane: ['Sophisticated' laptop bomb on Somali plane got through X-ray machine](http://www.cnn.com/2016/02/11/africa/somalia-plane-bomb/)

> The explosive device built into a laptop computer that detonated last week on a Somali passenger jet was "sophisticated" and got past X-ray machines at the Mogadishu airport, a source close to the investigation told CNN [...] The device blew a hole in the skin of the Daallo Airlines plane on February 2 but did not down the aircraft, because it detonated 20 minutes into the flight, before it reached cruising altitude.